# How to AutoComplete TextView when user input random sequence completion?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I want my AutoCompleteTextView to show suggestions when user input texts in a random sequence.

For example: if the word is "abcdefg" then I want to show the suggestion to this word in AutoCompleteTextView when user input "cde".

Comment: Removed a few redundant words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement with this logic

**let say you have something like this**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    String[] numbers ={"one","two","three",".four","five"};  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of numbers 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, numbers);  
        //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView  
        AutoCompleteTextView actv =  (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);  
        actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character  
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView  
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I want to show AutoCompleteTextView suggestion in "three" when the user input "hre". In this case, it is not possible. Here it only shows suggestions when user input from starting of the word ie. "th" (Threshold(2)).

Comment: Since you're using the above logic, the best approach is to override it's getFilter() method. Here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter%28%29)